# Woo commerce and mijireh checkout breaking when shipping is enabled

Tags: php, woocommerce, mijireh

I keep getting this error when i enable shipping on woocommerce,

I don't know whats breaking it, i assume its something to do with taxes and shipping not adding correctly? Seems to me a mijireh bug though as paypal checkout works fine

Mijireh error:{"total":["must add up correctly to the items, discount, tax and shipping costs"]}

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using the PayTrail payment gateway.

It came down to a change in the way shipping taxes are rounded which came in when I updated to woocommerce 2.1.7 - PayTrail would throw an error if the shipping + shipping tax included fractions of a cent.

To test and as a short-term fix, I first turned off the shipping tax. When that passed, I turned the tax back on and adjusted the shipping rates so that adding the tax would evaluate to a value with maximum 2 decimal places - i.e €4,75 + 24% shipping tax = €5,89. That passed as well.

Updating woocommerce and the PayTrail Gateway plugin a few days later fixed the bug.

Check out the **woocommerce 2.1.9** changelog - http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/changelog/

Fix number 4 should solve your problem:

> "Fix - Stop sending line items to Mijireh. Like PayPal, Mijireh struggles with out prices including tax due to rounding errors. Since the validation cannot be disabled, its better to just send the order as 1 item. This will prevent rounding errors and payment failures. Prices excluding tax are unaffected."